# Working examples of text messages, hover and editors with readonly html

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm wanting to get in to VSCode extension development but I've having a really tough time using some of the APIs without working examples or at least code snippits. I don't see the mapping from the documentation to the code.

I want to try and use Hovers but I haven't been able to locate any simple working examples anywhere ("Hello World" of Hovers). Where might I find working examples or code snippits of this?

I'm also very new to Typescript so maybe it's just not clicking for me. Here's what the documentation says: [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#Hover)